# Eval is not taking value from hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net page in .Net 2.0. There is a `hidden field` whose value is set from code behind. I used `Eval` expression as listed below to display the value of hidden field in a `label`. But this is dislayed as blank value. (I verified that the hidden field has value).

What need to be corrected to get the value displayed in the label?

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidCountIDSelected" name="hidCountIDSelected" value="" runat="Server" />

<asp:Label ID="lblPhysInvID" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("hidCountIDSelected") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Note: I know that I can do it with javascript/jquery. But I am not interested in that. I am looking for an asp.net solution

**UPDATE**

I have seen it using like the one below

```
 <%= strPhysicalInventoryText %>
```

Where `strPhysicalInventoryText` is a property

**REFERENCES**

1. [Filling multiple literals with the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853716/filling-multiple-literals-with-the-same-value)
2. [#EVAL vs #BIND](http://forums.asp.net/t/1097781.aspx?+EVAL+vs+BIND)

Comment: If you are downvoting, please be kind to put the reason too...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to Eval, but that's the wrong context. Eval is for when you're data binding. You're just setting the value of a property (not databinding).

From code behind, set the Text equivalent to the hidden field's value.

```
lblPhysInvID.Text = hidCountIDSelected.Value;
```

If you want to do it declaratively, then try something like this:

```
<%= hidCountIDSelected.Value %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eval is used when data binding.  If all you are doing is is setting the value of the hidden field then this should work for you, given that hidCountIdSelected is an integer.  Note that you do not need the `runat="server"` property.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidCountIDSelected" name="hidCountIDSelected" value="<%=hidCountIDSelected.ToString() %>" />
```